# Plesk cron iOS notifications randomly stopped working

Tags: centos, cron, ios

Recently, I started getting these cron error from Plesk. This cron controls push notifications to Plesk Manager on my iPhone/iPad. Obviously, turning off the cron stops the error but I want the cron to run to receive push notifications from my server.

**Cron Error Notification**

```
Cron <root@myserverdomain> /usr/local/psa/admin/bin/php -c '/usr/local/psa/admin/conf/php.ini' -dauto_prepend_file=sdk.php '/usr/local/psa/admin/plib/modules/plesk-mobile/scripts/push_worker.php'
```

**Cron Error**

```
ERROR ApnsPHP_Exception: (0) Unable to connect to 'ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195':  (0)
```

This is a screenshot of the cron in Plesk (now it's off)
[image]

I've made no changes to these files or the cron task, so I am stumped as to why it all of a sudden stopped working.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried running the cron job manually? Have you tried connecting to gateway.push.apple.com on port 2195?

Comment: Yes I have tried and it does connect... `Connected to gateway.push.apple.com.`

Comment: It doesn't look like this is a cron error at all; cron is working fine.  This is an error from your script.  However, with no information about your script at all, we cannot help you.

Answer (score 1):

Did you check if your push certificate is stil valid and not expired?

You can check in the provisoning portal. You can get vague errors when the certificate is expired, you just have to generate a new one.

I strongly suspect this is the issue because you stated you didn't change anything.

Comment: I never created the original certificate though, since it was installed by Plesk. Also... this is what the file looks like http://d.pr/lfIh

Comment: I don't have any experience with this Plesk function, but possibly there is a separate certificate file somewhere. See if you can find a file with extension .pem or .p12 or .cer